# Why does my method has the same name as class?

Tags: java, methods, jlist

I have created a JDialog using this code:

```
public class GUIsub extends JFrame {

private JLabel item1;

public GUIsub() {
    super("The title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        item1 = new JLabel("This is a JLabel!");
        item1.setToolTipText("Are you hovering?!");
        add(item1);
    }   
}
```

Why does my method have to have the same name as my class? What are the benefits of it and can I get the same result using another name? If so, how? And why do I have to extend to JFrame, why can't I just import the necessary libraries?

I am really confused about this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask **two** questions in a question. Ask one question. If you have two questions, post them separately. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for that, I did not know.

Comment: You should really read about the *very basics* of OOP and Java. This is explained in the first 5 minutes of every OOP tutorial.

Comment: First learn Java, then start learning Swing. You should know about the basic concepts like types, inheritance, constructors etc before digging into additional libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does my method have to have the same name as my class?

It's not a method, it's a [*constructor*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8). Using the name of the class when declaring the constructor is just the way that the Java language designers decided to indicate that it's a constructor rather than a method. (It's a common pattern, some other languages do it too, including C++ [which partially inspired Java] and C# [which was partially inspired by Java].)

> And why do I have to extend to JFrame, why can't I just import the necessary libraries?

It's really best on SO to ask **one** question/question.

You have to extend `JFrame` because the GUI system you're working with works with instances of `JFrame`. As far as it knows, instances of your class *are* `JFrame`s, and it uses methods defined on `JFrame` when interacting with those instances. This could have been done with interfaces, but the designers in this case went with a base class instead.

Answer (score 1):

public GUIsub() is not a method, it is a constructor. Constructors must have the same name as the class in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`public GUIsub()` is the constructor of the class ... 
you can use it for "preparing the object for been used later"...